# Run Visual Studio 2022 without admin rights on Windows 11

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I installed Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11. When I launch it, it's always run with admin rights. I want to run it without admin rights. My Windows has only one account, which has an admin rights.x

What I did:

- Confirmed "Run as administrator" is unchecked in the property of VS2022.
- Changed the ownership of `dev.envexe` from admin to users.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you get a UAC prompt if you start regedit?

Comment: Win+R, and typed `regedit`. The text "This task is run with administrator rights" (I translated) was shown just below the text input. It didn't show any UAC. I haven't seen UAC when I use Visual Studio 2022 so far as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have UAC disabled or your "one acount" is literally the  built-in Administrator account (can be renamed).  In this case the account always has the elevated token and UAC is bypassed. It's not possible to run as not admin.  You'll need to create another account and login with that account instead. As it is your effectively logging in directly like root on unix.

Comment: Thanks. UAC was disabled by default. Does Turning it on solve a problem? I haven't used windows for 10y and I'm trying to catch up.

Comment: I set UAC at its highest level and now Visual Studio 2022 runs without admin rights. I'm not sure what's going on, but anyway, Thanks!