# Visual Studio 2022 once run as ADMIN never goes back to normal

Tags: admin, visual-studio-2022

It is amazing that no one in the world can solve this problem. See for instance,
[Run Visual Studio 2022 without admin rights on Windows 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75141753/run-visual-studio-2022-without-admin-rights-on-windows-11)

I have created an another account in Windows 10 and run Visual Studio. Just in first use, Visual Studio somehow inherit from it the ADMIN property.

I googled it, and Microsoft employees always suggest to the asking persons naive solutions that absolutely don't work, e.g., Properties of the file.

The fact is: once you run Visual Studio 2022 elevated as 'admin', it seems IMPOSSIBLE to run it back again in 'normal' privileges.

I have installed and uninstalled VS 2022, several times, changing from Community Version to Professional Version and vice-versa. It seems that this information is "saved in another dimension", since I can't locate where the command "run as admin" comes from.

[image: ADMIN notice]

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio 2022 as a shortcut or opening `devenv.exe` directly? If a shortcut; under `Properties > Shortcut > Advanced`, "Run as administrator" is unchecked, correct?

Comment: @chrisbyte. Correct. "Run as administrator" is unchecked. I just found a solution. See my answer. As I have suspected, is kind of a bug from the "Windows 10", account privileges system.

Answer (score 1):

I have followed the instructions carefully from 'James Erikson' and worked!

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/user-account-control-not-working/bcc6bce4-a449-4fa6-9cfc-84cba690a72e
 [>User Account Control Not Working<](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/user-account-control-not-working/bcc6bce4-a449-4fa6-9cfc-84cba690a72e)

In case that the link above has be broken, follows below his instructions (copied *ipsis litteris*):

"I have finally fixed this!!!!

Make sure you log out of ALL accounts before doing this!!

Okay so, log onto your administrator account. Open the RUN command by opening the start menu, then typing "Run". Press enter. You'll see a dialog with a place to type... Type in: "NETPLWIZ" (you can type all lowercase, I typed in uppercase so you know which keys to press) and press enter...

A window will come up with your user accounts. I bet you that under the "group" section, you'll see at least one account with 2 groups assigned to it. What you need to do is click on that account to select it, then click "Properties"... click the "Group Membership" tab on the top of the window that'll open, then select "Other" for it's group... In the drop down box next to "Other", either select "Users" or "Administrators", depending on what you want that account to have. Users is for standard user, and Administrators is for a regular administrator account.

Do this to any and all accounts that you have listed! otherwise this wont work!

Then, after clicking apply and okay to all of those windows, log out of all accounts... Now, you'll be able to log into your standard account and be able to run administrative programs!!!!"

If it still doesn't work, then you may have to set up a new admin account and do the same procedure to make sure it's set to only the Administrators group..."